# Count Nodes Equal to Average of Subtree

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary-tree

I'm the beginner for python,and I always feel confused about binary tree when I practise in leetcode.
Here is my code:

```
from typing import Optional

#Definition for a binary tree node.(This is given by leetcode)
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution(object):
    def averageOfSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        ans = 0
        def traverse(node):
            if node is None:
                return (0,0)

            left = traverse(node.left)
            right = traverse(node.right)

            total = left[0] + right[0] + node.val
            count = left[1] + right[1] +1

            if total // count == node.val:
                nonlocal ans
                ans += 1
            return (total, count)

        traverse(root)
        return ans
                       

root = [4,8,5,0,1,None,6]
a = Solution()
print(a.averageOfSubtree(root))
```

The TreeNode definition is given by leetcode, and I just copy down and run on my vscode, however, it hint an error:**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'left'**
How can I modify it?

Comment: If you'll notice from the typehint, this function expects root to be a TreeNode. It is not. The python error tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: If you are given that list as an input, then you have to convert it into a tree using multiple TreeNode objects before you can use averageOfSubtree (as defined here)